# how do i get values stored in struct?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to retrieve values from an array of structs. I do not know the correct ways to retrieve them.

Here is my struct:

```
struct entry{
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    int mark;
};

typedef struct entry Acct;
Acct dism2A03[MAX_ENTRY];
```

How i assigned values:

```
void add_new(char *name,int mark){
    printf("%s,%d",name,mark);
    int v=0;
    v=entry_total;
    strcpy(dism2A03[v].name,name);
    dism2A03[v].mark = mark;
}
```

What i tried (DOES NOT WORK):

```
int m=0;
for(m=0;m<MAX_ENTRY;m++){
                char name[NAME_SIZE] = dism2A03[m].name;
    line 75 >>          int mark = dism2A03[m].mark;
                printf("\nEntry %d",m);
                printf("%s",name);
                printf("%d",mark);
             }
```

ERROR:
    p9t2.c: In function ‘main’:
    p9t2.c:75:5: error: invalid initializer

Comment: Define "DOES NOT WORK" for us.

Comment: i will edit in the errors, thanks!

Comment: How you call `add_new` ?
`char name = getfield(dism2A03[m],'name');` and `char name[NAME_SIZE] = dism2A03[m].name;` doesn't make sense

Comment: Great. Now, you can't access members using strings like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt implies existence of `getfield` function that takes a `struct` and a multicharacter `char` literal and gets the field; there is no such function in C.

Your second attempt is much closer: rather than trying to assign the name to an array, assign it to a `char` pointer, like this:

```
int m=0;
for(m=0;m<MAX_ENTRY;m++){
    // Since you aren't planning on modifying name through pointer,
    // you can declare the pointer const to make your intentions clear.
    const char *name = dism2A03[m].name;
    int mark = dism2A03[m].mark;
    printf("\nEntry %d",m);
    printf("%s",name);
    printf("%d",mark);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it is working after making that minor change!!